# Merging plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created several plots in ggplot called stored as plot1, plot2, plot3

I would like to create a single plot where each of the plots are displayed in subplots.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grid.arrange` from package `gridExtra`:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3)
```

An example:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point()
plot2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, hp)) +
  geom_line()
plot3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(vs, qsec)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 might I suggest to use `arrangeGrob` rather than `grid.arrange` to get (more suitable for `print` and `ggsave`)